# How would i reduce wordpress website loading time?

Tags: wordpress, gzip, mobile-website, web-testing

Website URL:[www.komalseo21.com](http://www.komalseo21.com)
Hosting Site: [www.squarebrothers.com](http://www.squarebrothers.com)

I have made my blog using wordpress platform. It takes 28 seconds while loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the factors that you can use to decrease loading time

- Use an effective caching plugin ( W3 Total Cache or wp-rocket)
- Use CDN
- Optimize Images
- Reduce the number of posts on the home page

Hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Add Cache Plugin Like.. WP Super cache https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/